# Get variable from another script

Tags: variables, applescript

In applescript can you use a variable that was defined in another script? 
I think you would have something like:

```
set test to (load script "/tmp/a.scpt")
```

But how would you pick a specific variable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use property variables in your external script

e.g, a.scpt:

```
property foo : "hello world"
```

...and in the calling script you use the "*x of n*" style of referencing.

```
set test to (load script "/tmp/a.scpt")
display dialog (the foo of test)
```

You can also access the returned result of a handler in the external script.

e.g,
a.scpt:

```
on getChoice()
    set res to choose from list {"one fish", "two fish", "red fish", "blue fish"}
    return res
end getChoice
```

...and in the calling script:

```
set choice to getChoice() of test
```

Comment: I have this in a handler and it says "Expected “end” but found “property”."

Comment: @qwertyk31 property variables need to be declared outside any handlers, this is my guess at your issue. They are like global variables so all code in the same script can access them. See this for a breakdown of var types https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/applescript/conceptual/applescriptlangguide/conceptual/ASLR_variables.html

Comment: When I put the property var outside of the handler the script runs but what I need is to use a handler to run a "choose from list" and get the result in the original script